# C# Filtering collections through extended functions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, extension-methods

I have the below line in my code.

My expctation is `SkipWhile()` will block nulls and will pass only valid values to ForEach(). But nulls are also getting passed to `ForEach()`.  What could be failing in this code?

```
logChildFolder.SkipWhile(path1 => string.IsNullOrEmpty(path1))
            .ToList<string>()
            .ForEach(path2 => copyLogFiles(args.SetupInfo.SetupDataFolder, path2));
```

Comment: As @Guffa said below, `ToList()` wastes memory and processing time unnecessary, as it creates an in-memory copy of all the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) method, i.e.:

```
logChildFolder.Where(path1 => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(path1))
```

Suppose in your code values in `logChildFolder` are: `null`, `a`, `b`, `null`. `logChildFolder.SkipWhile(path1 => string.IsNullOrEmpty(path1))` will return `a`, `b`, `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The `SkipWhile` method will only skip the first items as long as there are nulls, as soon as there is a non-null value it will just let the rest of the items through. Use the `Where` method to filter the items.

Also, you are mixing functional style with non-functional style. Just use a `foreach` loop to loop the items. That will save you from creating an intermittent list also:

```
foreach (string path in logChildFolder.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))) {
  copyLogFiles(args.SetupInfo.SetupDataFolder, path);
}
```